# Symfony2 Use parameters in EntityRepository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am wondering if this is even a good practice. But for my project i need to get a parameter from `parameters.yml` and use it inside `EntityRepository`.
So for this I created a service but still the call is not executed.

```
services:
    xxx_repository:
        class: XXX\DatabaseBundle\Repository\CitiesRepository
        calls:
            - [setTheParameter, ["%the_parameter%"]]
```

> parameters.yml

```
...
the_parameter: 14400
...
```

And inside the CitiesRepository.php I am doing the following:

```
class CitiesRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $theParameter;

    public function setTheParameter($theParameter)
    {
        $this->theParameter = $theParameter;
    }
    ....
}
```

But $this->theParameter is always null.

SO i have 2 questions: Is this a healthy habit? And why is the result always null?

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `theParameter` inside the `__construct()` method?

Comment: if i pass it as an argument and if it does not extend EntityRepository...

Comment: Your code looks fine. And if you try receive your service through container like: `$this->getContainer()->get('xxx_repository');`  all will be fine, and all will be work. And you need just check param `the_parameter` in a `parameters.yml` that it value not `null` and not `~`.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak I am not sure I understand. Where should I call the container->get ?

Comment: From place where you would like use repository (controller, command, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getRepository` method of the `doctrine` service as factory:

```
xxx_repository:
    class: XXX\DatabaseBundle\Repository\CitiesRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine", "getRepository"]
    arguments: ["DatabaseBundle:City"]
    calls:
        - ["setTheParameter", ["%the_parameter%"]]
```

And then you can access to this repository as service in your controller:

```
$this->get('xxx_repository');
```